# InfiniteLoop in useEffect when one of the dependency is a function from useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

2021 UPDATE

Use a library that makes requests and cache them - react-query, swr, redux-toolkit-query

ORIGINAL QUESTION

I've been struggling with this for quite a long time and didn't find an answer.

I have a component that is the last step of some registration process during which I ask a user to enter its data through several forms. In this component, I send collected data to API. If the request is successful I show ok, if not I show error.

I have useEffect that sends the data. The function that performs this task lives in a context

```
  const { sendDataToServer } = useContext(context)

  useEffect(() => {
    const sendData = async () => {
      setLoading(true)
      await sendDataToServer(...data)
      setLoading(false)
    }
    sendData()
  }, [sendDataToServer, data])
```

If I include sendDataToServer in the dependencies list this useEffect would go into an infinite loop, causing endless rerendering. I suppose this is because a reference to the function has a different value on every render.

I can of course redesign the app and do not keep the function in the context, but I do like it and don't consider it a bad practice (correct me if I am wrong)

So what are my options here? How do I keep the flow with the context API, but use useEffect with the correct list of dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right with your guess, that's why we got [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) for referential equality.

You didn't post the `sendDataToServer` function, but it should look something like this with `useCallback`:

```js
const sendDataToServer = useCallback(data => {
    // your implementation
}, [your, dependencies])
```

After that you can safely use it in your useEffect.

I highly recommend Kent C. Dodd's blog posts:   [When to useMemo and useCallback](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback)

Smartassing now: If it's only purpose is sending data to the server (and not changing the app's state), I don't know why it should be part of the context. It could be a custom hook or even a static function.

Btw: There could be another problem: If the `data` dependency in your `useEffect` is changed when executing `sendDataToServer`, you will still have an endless loop (e. g. when you fetch the new data after executing `sendDataToServer`), but we can't see the rest of the code.

Comment: sendData is like: 1. dispatch loading, 2. axios post 3. dispatch success. I tried to useCallback in component itself, so useEffect will call send = useCallback(sendData) but that didn't make much sense so far. I will try your solution, thanks!

Comment: interesting, it works in most cases, but if I have dependency from state, like statuses: loading, success, error - then of course it goes to infinite loop. So not really clear what is the best pattern will be, I want to keep function that manipulate state as part of the provider, but I cannot import them in components perfectly, seems like catch-22

Comment: Usually I have a custom hook to access data in the application (like `useStatuses`), which gets data from either context (or remotely fetched).  On how to structure your context, I highly recommend Kent C. Dodds' article: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively    ...and, to simplify remote data with React, I also highly recommend "React Query", which a) fetches and b) caches data, so you don't need to do that in a React context yourself for your server data:  https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query